# Flutter problemas al llamar future de tipo bool

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta función en flutter, que devuelve true o false:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando llamo a la función con la sentencia IF me aparece un error:
Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal ves por que no esperas a que el resultado se regrese, podrias intentar colocar un `await`, para mayor claridad de tu pregunta, recomiendo que coloques el código. en lugar de imagenes

Comment: No pude agregar el código por que no me dejaba guardar la pregunta. El await iría en el el if??

Comment: Si podría ser en el if, otra forma seria antes, algo similar a la respuesta que acabo de colocar.

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues comentarios o edites tu pregunta para mostrar mas información sobre el error que te muestra, edite mi respuesta para que tengas un mejor ejemplo de como aplicar el `await`

Comment: Necesitas usar FutureBuilder/Streams/StatefulWidget para refrescar el widget ya que es una petición asincrona

Answer (score 0):

A lo que puedo observar, es por que no esperas que el método se resuelva, por lo tanto tienes que colocar un `await`, una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente

```
if(await _verificaContacto() == false)
```

pero para mejor claridad y comodidad lo prefiero de la siguiente manera

```
final result = await _verificaContacto();

if(!result){
...
}
```

Para que tu método no marque algún error por el `await` debe tener `async`
algo similar a lo siguiente

```
void esperandoRespuesta() async {
    final result = await _verificaContacto();

    if(!result){
    ...
    }
}
```

podrías revisar la [documentación](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await) para mas ejemplos.